# /etc/rc.local fail on boot with "Failed at step STDOUT spawning /etc/rc.local: No such device" in /var/log/syslog

Tags: boot, systemd-startup

I am trying to diagnose why /etc/rc.local is not successfully executing on boot of a raspberry pi.

I have stripped the content of /etc/rc.local to a minimal version, and still cannot get it to touch a file in the /tmp directory.

I am getting this relevant output in /var/log/syslog on startup.

So looks like systemd is responsible for executing /etc/rc.local but is failing.

Have done lots of googling, no luck yet.

Thanks

**Notes**

System info (new to raspberry pi so let me know what else i can post):

`uname -a`:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.14.79-v7+ #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

`/etc/rc.local` content:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
touch /tmp/foo

exit 0
```

`/var/log/syslog` content:

```
raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
raspberrypi systemd[290]: rc-local.service: Failed at step STDOUT spawning /etc/rc.local: No such device
raspberrypi systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=209
raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
raspberrypi systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Unit entered failed state.
raspberrypi systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

`/etc/rc.local` appears to have correct permissions:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -la /etc/rc.local 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 345 Jan 16 18:03 /etc/rc.local
```

**Edit/Update:**

I ended up abandoning attempts to start my server via `/etc/rc.local` and instead created a systemd unit, which was pretty straight forward.

Guide here : https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-run-a-raspberry-pi-program-on-startup

Comment: Is your rootfs read-only? Where's your /tmp? Is it part of the rootfs? Or a tmpfs file system?

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). Following the recommendation of the developers from systemd you should avoid using it. Instead you should create a systemd unit file for your script.

Comment: I went with a systemd unit, as @Ingo suggested and everything started working as desired.

Comment: @Dougie the /tmp is part of the root filesystem.

Comment: Please make your Edit/Update an answer. This will finish your question and shows other user that it has a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not end up getting my additions to `/etc/rc.local` to correctly execute.

Instead created a systemd unit, which was pretty straight forward, and is recommended over additions to `/etc/rc.local`.

Guide here : https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-run-a-raspberry-pi-program-on-startup

Please comment with better guides and I will edit the answer.